# Count unique values from duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have following data on the table.

```
Uid | comm | status
-------------------
12    23     eve
15    23     eve
20    23     mon
12    23     mon
20    23     eve
17    23     mon
```

how do i query to get below result to avoid duplicates and make sure if i count uid for "eve" and same uid appears on "mon" then count only uid for "eve"?

```
count | status
-------------------
3         eve
1         mon
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query in order to pick each `Uid` value once:

```
SELECT Uid, MIN(status)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Uid
```

**Output:**

```
Uid MIN(status)
---------------
12  eve
15  eve
17  mon
20  eve
```

Using the above query you can get at the desired result like this:

```
SELECT status, count(*)
from (
   SELECT Uid, MIN(status) AS status
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY Uid ) AS t
GROUP BY status
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/WGD33415)